# Relative positioning goes wrong according to absolute

Tags: html, css, position

So I made [JsFidle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gy3FU/1/) and I'm troubled about relative and absolute positiong. So  I made absolute div called top. I've got relative long (wide) blue panel with title that is positionend properly - top 0px. but when i'm making 2nd div in div id=top it has relative positioning top=70px (70 px is size of wide blue panel above). Sounds okey, right? But it isn't. I have no idea why It has so bad positoning . its relative to div="top" div, right? So why it moves so to bottom. Help please.

```
#top {
position: absolute;
top:0;
height:420px;

#panel {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
top:0px;

#panel-pic {
position: relative;
top: 70px;
height:350px;
background-color:black;
background-position: center;
background-size:cover;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 9px black;
```

}

panel-pic goes wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing the two. :)
The parent should be relative and all elements you want to place relative-ly to it, should be absolute.
So just change #top's position to relative, and all others to absolute.

Comment: so relative = position div under another relative div with +x px to for example top?

Comment: Imagine #div_parent and #div_child. In order to move #div_child relatively to #div_parent, in your case, you must apply position:relative to #div_parent and position: absolute to #div_child.

Comment: Absolute means "Position with respect to the edges of the nearest ancestor that is not-position static". Relative is "Position with respect to where it would be if it was not positioned". (Relative is usually more usefully used to just stop an element from being position static).

Answer (score 0):

under `#panel-pic p {`

`margin-top: 175px;`

should be

`margin-top: 0px;`

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gy3FU/7/